# I am new to C++ and I am not sure how to input more than one line of numbers from a .txt file

Tags: c++

My data.txt file currently looks like this:

```
32
99
135
0
-999
```

So what I want to do is have something like this outputted to my result.txt file:

```
Centigrade to Farenheit is [insert value here]
Centigrade to Farenheit is [insert value here]
Centigrade to Farenheit is [insert value here]
Centigrade to Farenheit is [insert value here]
-999
```

I want my program to read more than one line in order to finally read -999, which will tell it to stop. At least, that's what I think the problem is.

This is what I have so far:

```
void main ()   
{

    ifstream ins; // associates ins as an input stream
    ofstream outs // associates outs as an output stream
    float centigrade, farenheit;

    ins.open(in_file); // associating files with streams
    outs.open(out_file);
    ins >> centigrade;

    // input values for centigrade from file data.txt
       cout << centigrade <<  endl;
    // echo print input to screen
    // processing data 
       while (centigrade !=-999)
       {     // Calculate farenheit
           farenheit=centigrade*9/5+32;
               // Output farenheit
               cout << "Farenheit of " << setprecision(5)
               << centigrade << " " << "is" 
               << " " << setprecision(5) << farenheit << endl;

       // output result to file result.txt
       outs << "Centigrade to Farenheit is: " << farenheit << endl;
       ins.close () ; // closing input file
       outs.close (); // closing output file
       }

       _getch(); // holding the screen
} // end main
```

Comment: Do a loop `while` you can read input, `break` out of the loop when the input is the sentinel value (`-999`).

Comment: Be careful when comparing floats. The internal representation of the literal `-999` and your converted value might not be the same, which causes the while condition to fail. It is better to check for  `while( centigrade > -300 )` as a check for `-999`.

Comment: @tillaert Or if there's only integers in the input file then read as integers. Optionally read as `float` and do a check for `static_cast<int>(std::ceil(valueRead)) == -999`.

Answer (score 1):

In your program, you are only reading the input once, and then closing the input file inside your loop.

You need to use your loop to keep reading from your input file until the value you read is the one that indicates you are done, `-999`. Close the input file when you have left the loop.

```
    std::string number;

    ins.open(in_file); // associating files with streams
    outs.open(out_file);

    while ((ins >> number) && (number != "-999")) {
        centigrade = std::stof(number);
        //...do something with centigrade
    }

    ins.close();
    outs.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't have a clear question and at the same time your program contains several problems, I will try to address them and correct your code.

1. Be careful when comparing floats to other numbers such as -999, because it might fail due to float nature. Floating point math is not exact, it was designed to represent wide range of possible values but with some approximation.
   For example these checks fail on my machine:
   assert((long int)16777217.0f == 16777217);
   assert(111111.0f + 1000000.0f == 11111111.0f);
   If it's too complicated to understand for now, then just use integer for centigrade for now.
2. You close ins and outs in the loop, but you must do it after the loop.
3. You read centigrade only one, although you should read it in the loop.

   void main()
   {
       ifstream ins;
       ofstream outs;

   ```
   ins.open(in_file);
   outs.open(out_file);

   do
   {
       int centigrade = 0;
       ins >> centigrade;
       if (centigrade == -999)
           break;

       cout << centigrade << endl;

       float farenheit = (centigrade * 9 / 5.0f) + 32.0f;
       cout << "Farenheit of " << setprecision(5)
            << centigrade << " " << "is" 
            << " " << setprecision(5) << (int)farenheit << endl;

       outs << "Centigrade to Farenheit is: " << farenheit << endl;
   }
   ins.close();
   outs.close();

   _getch();
   ```

   }